# Is there a way to "auto-tune" network interface interrupt mapping in Ubuntu 20.04 with the PREEMPT_RT patch applied?

Tags: networking, interrupt, ubuntu-20.04, preempt-rt

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel NUC (call it **Beta**) and applied the PREEMPT_RT patch so I can run (near) real-time tasks on it. For this to work I need <500us ping to another machine on the network, but right now it is slow and also varies quite a bit:

`rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.148/0.829/2.360/0.224 ms`

I have a similar setup running on another NUC (call it **Alpha**) where I get much better ping. This is running a different version of the kernel which does not work with the newer NUC (drivers seem incompatible). Comparing the output of `cat /proc/interrupts | grep <interface-name>` on the two, I found that on Alpha, the settings were configured such that the network interface is "mapped" to all the cores.

**Alpha** (fast ping)

```
 156:          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          2  IR-PCI-MSI 46137344-edge      enp88s0
 157:     130151      90842      24003     123920      38044     365508     209425     160927  IR-PCI-MSI 46137345-edge      enp88s0-TxRx-0
 158:      44674      38892      16777     164096      24533     158460      18639      31108  IR-PCI-MSI 46137346-edge      enp88s0-TxRx-1
 159:     272798     111246      12902     165234      44009     107443      48298     111897  IR-PCI-MSI 46137347-edge      enp88s0-TxRx-2
 160:      48671      44626      32107      52454      32232      56264     202022      30701  IR-PCI-MSI 46137348-edge      enp88s0-TxRx-3
```

**Beta** (slow ping)

```
 162:          0          0          0          4          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 45088768-edge      enp86s0
 163:          0          0          0          0          0          0          7     262533          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 45088769-edge      enp86s0-TxRx-0
 164:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         10          0          0          0          0          0          0     210802          0  IR-PCI-MSI 45088770-edge      enp86s0-TxRx-1
 165:          0          0          0          0          0     154417          0          0          8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 45088771-edge      enp86s0-TxRx-2
 166:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          9          0     265804          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 45088772-edge      enp86s0-TxRx-3
```

Could this be the problem? And if it is, is there a way to "auto-tune" the interrupt mapping?